# Can an arbitrary circuit be represented using two commands (qsel package)?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

I was watching this entertaining video by David Bacon (as in "Bacon-Shor code", Cirq, ...) :
[video of talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xp1QJCMLULo) where he mentions the package he wrote:

> ([qsel](https://github.com/dabacon/qsel)), that describes simulating quantum circuits using two commands : "entanglement" and "superposition".

This seems bizarre. There's no documentation on how to start with a circuit and end up in a sequence of such commands. Is anyone familiar with the package or the underlying idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qsel is an esoteric programming language similar to [Ook!](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ook!) or [whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace).

All it's doing is requiring you to decompose the circuit into the gateset [CS, H] and then representing the circuit with a ridiculous format. This is possible because [CS, H] is universal and because anything and everything can be efficiently encoded into a binary system that uses two symbols; that's fundamental to how computers work in the first place.

Comment: I see...so it's more of a joke than anything deep or useful. (btw you're mentioned in a few slides of the talk as you probably know)